# Quiz master agent using reinforcement learning

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, deep-learning, reinforcement-learning, artificial-intelligence

I am working on developing a quiz master agent using reinforcement learning.

Please verify my approach and provide feedback.
Also, please suggest which reinforcement learning methods are suitable to solve this problem ?

Assume that Quiz master has 100 questions in question bank.

Task : Ask any ten questions to student. 

Goal : Collect maximum reward by receiving more incorrect answers from student.

Action : 
Publish next question.

Reward : 
+1 if student gives wrong answer.
+1 if student doesn't answer.
-1 if student gives right answer.

State : 
Answer status(Right answer,Wrong answer,Don't know, Takes time)
Student performance status(Low, Average, High)